# Bead moving along a free ring that is initially at rest

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, centripetal-force

> Consider this diagram in which the ring of mass $M$ is at rest initially and the bead of mass $m$ has velocity $u$ as shown.
> [image: 1]

Why isn't the force of interaction (normal force) between the bead and ring $mu^2/r$?. I know the ring will start moving after $t>0$ but initial if we calculate normal reaction shouldn't it be $mu^2/r$ (as the ring is at rest, initially)? However, it is $(Mmu^2)/R(M+m)$. Also, the normal reaction doesn't change with time and I don't understand why?

Comment: I think we need a bit more information.  You mention that a point is not fixed, but not which point is unfixed nor what its non-fixed motion is.  Also you say "the ring will start moving after t > 0", but don't describe the motion of the ring.  Can you please add in a bit more detail along these lines?

Comment: @Cort Ammon Sorry for the inconvenience. I have made the necessary edits
The ring is initially at rest and it would start moving due to interaction force with bead as you can see. The point i meant was centre of ring.

Comment: It seems to me that the interaction forces should do no work? In the absence of external forces the bead rotates and the ring stays wherever it was initially placed.

Comment: @Albertus Magnus  interaction force does no work. correct. But surely the energy of bead gets converted to both of ring and bead... there is normal reaction pulling the ring , causing it to move (ring isn't fixed). You can also see that at any point momentum has to be conserved, even if the bead's velocity becomes along x-axis , so there must be some ring velocity in order to compensate the momentums in both the directions (y and x)

Comment: @PinkAura Ok, so you are envisioning a system of bead and ring, both of which are initially at rest, then the system experiences an external force, an impulse to the bead; however, conservation of momentum requires that the system be closed and not subject to external forces.

Comment: @Albertus Magnus the bead is not at rest initially

Comment: i think you got me wrong, the initial scenario describes bead having velocity $u$ and ring at rest... no external force acts

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus I am really sorry for inconvenience, but let me show you in the diagram can you please come to chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151945/discussion-between-pinkaura-and-albertus-magnus).

Comment: @PinkAura I have had some time to think more about the issue. The interaction forces of the bead and ring are *internal* forces for the system, they do indeed cancel.  When we push against a box, the forces on the hand-box interface are internal and cancel (why your hand doesn't go through the box), however, the box still experiences an *external* force. In the case of the ring/bead system there is no external force.

Comment: @AlbertusMagnus When you consider them as a system, they cancel (that's why i was saying external force on the system is zero) but if you consider them separately, they don't cancel, You push against a box, box does move so there is external force on box, and( why your hand doesn't go into it, i think it's more related to pressure and properties of box like if its rigid or non rigid etc, consider pushing with a needle in a non rigid box),, in my case  if you consider ring as separate entity, there is external force accelerating it

Comment: Try considering bead and ring as separate entity, draw their fbd separately, there wouldn't be any force balancing on the ring to stop it from accelerating

Comment: Ok Got it, I can calculate that!

Comment: There is no reason why the interaction forces will be the same. If the ring were fixed, the centripetal force $mu^2/R$ will be provided by whatever is fixing the ring in place. But in this case, that force doesn't exist.

Comment: @VincentThacker okay, i think bead would also be having an acceleration opposite to the $u²/R$ at the initial moment as well, so we can't use that ig

Answer (score 2):

If there are no forces on the system, the center of mass will move with constant velocity.  At the initial moment, the CM is moving upwards at a speed of $m u / (m+M)$.

So let's look at the system in the frame in which the CM is at rest.  At the initial moment, the bead is moving upwards at a speed of $v_b = M u /(m+M)$ and the ring is moving downwards at a speed of $v_r  = m u /(m+M)$.  Moreover, since the CM of the system must remain fixed in this frame, the bead and the center of the ring will have to "orbit around each other" (see the concept of the [barycentre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycenter_(astronomy)) in astronomy.)  Importantly, the radius of the bead's "orbit" in this frame will not be the entire radius $R$ of the ring, but will instead be the distance from the bead to the CM.

The above facts should let you calculate the contact force between the bead and the ring, as would be measured in the CM frame.  And since forces are the same in all reference frames, the result in the CM frame is the same as in the original "lab" frame.

Comment: This is the exact method my teacher used .. but I was trying to get the answer from ground frame at the initial moment ( as the question specifies). Still thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: My point in the last paragraph is that the force is the same in the CM frame as in the ground frame.  But if you're looking for a calculation done entirely in the ground frame, it could probably be done — it'll just be more complicated.

Comment: I tried to do it in the ground frame(you can see my solution), i believe it was somewhat simpler than cm frame, and yes force in the cm frame would be same in the ground frame

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your amazing answers ( I do see how different methods can be used to solve the same problem). I am adding my solution to the problem. I am solving this in the ground frame.

In the ground frame, initially, the bead has velocity $u$ and the ring is at rest.
Now, what i was missing in the question is that I didn't take the acceleration of ring into account. Initially, the ring has zero velocity but there would be Normal acceleration, hence acceleration.

For ring, $$N = Ma$$
where, $ a$ is initial acceleration of ring and $N$ is normal reaction force.

The acceleration $a$ would be *linear acceleration in the radial direction* for bead as well (it is bound to move along with ring)( this is what i was not considering),

for bead,
$$N = m(u^2/R - a)$$
where, $u^2/R$ is the centripetal acceleration.

solving all this we would get the same result.

Note that I solved this for the initial moment at time $t$=0.